# How can you remove the link to the twitter post when using Tweepy?

Tags: python, tweepy

I made a very simple function that just prints the latest tweet from a given user:

```py
def get_tweet(username):
    recent_tweets = self.twitter_api.user_timeline(username, page = 1)
    # I turn it into a string in order to remove the b' and ' at the beginning and end
    print(f"@{username}'s latest tweet is: \n{str(recent_tweets[0].text)[2:-1]}")
```

Say username is `SpaceX`, this would print:

"Crew Dragon and Falcon 9 in the hangar at Launch Complex 39A ahead of launching four astronauts to the... https://t.co/ cnkLRu8R08" (space added because SO doesn't allow shortned links)

However, I would like to remove the link to the tweet that is put at the end

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
def get_tweet(username):
     recent_tweets = self.twitter_api.user_timeline(username, page = 1)
     s = f"@{username}'s latest tweet is: \n{str(recent_tweets[0].text.encode("utf-8"))[2:-1]}"
     s = s.split()
     del s[-1]
     print(s)

get_tweet()
```

Comment: Thanks, didn't think of turning it into a list and taking all but the last value!

Comment: yep! no problem. If the solution worked for you then it'd be great if you could click the check next to my solution

Comment: also if you need to turn it back into a string then you can use " ".join(s)

Comment: I was planning on marking it as the answer but they have a time limit, but it's marked now.